# Python: Convert String with Unicode to HTML numeric code

Tags: python, html, unicode, converters

Hy guys i'm looking for a solution to convert all the unicodes contained in a string to the corresponding HTML entities.

For instance:

**input:**  "This is \u+0024. a string with \u+0024. random \u+0024. unicode" 
**output:** "This is &#36; a string with &#36; random &#36; unicode"

My current solution to this problem looks like:

```
if "\\u+" in my_string:
  unicode_code = (label_content.split("\\u+"))[1].split('.')[0]
  unicode_to_replace = f"\\u+{unicode_code}."
  unicode_string = f"U+{unicode_code}"
  html_code = unicode_string.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  my_string = label_content.replace(unicode_to_replace,  html_code)
```

But the unicode string is not converted in the right way, any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. 
Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer applying [Regular expression operations (`re` module)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). The `pattern` variable covers

- all valid Unicode values (see e.g. `U+042F` instead of the middle `U+0024`),
- all syntax versions of the input string: `input` variable in the original question was edited three times (*with/without* leading backslash *and/or* trailing dot), and
- `my_string` variable in the OQ's self answer is incorrect: `'\u+0024'` raises the *truncated \uXXXX escape* error.

The script:

```
import re

def UPlusHtml(matchobj):
    return re.sub( r"^\\?[uU]\+", '&#x', 
             re.sub( r'\.$', '', matchobj.group(0) ) ) + ';';

def UPlusRepl(matchobj):
    return chr( int( re.sub( r"^\\?[uU]\+", '', 
                       re.sub( r'\.$', '', matchobj.group(0) ) ),16 ) );

pattern = r"(\\?[uU]\+[0-9a-fA-F]+\.?)"

input = "This is U+0024. a string with U+042f random U+0024. unicode"

print( input )
print( re.sub( pattern, UPlusHtml, input ) )
print( re.sub( pattern, UPlusRepl, input ) )

print('--')

my_string =  "This is \\u+0024. a string with \\u+042F random \\u+0024. unicodes"

print( my_string )
print( re.sub( pattern, UPlusHtml, my_string ) )
print( re.sub( pattern, UPlusRepl, my_string ) )
```

**Output**: `\SO\67105976.py`

```
This is U+0024. a string with U+042f random U+0024. unicode
This is &#x0024; a string with &#x042f; random &#x0024; unicode
This is $ a string with Я random $ unicode
--
This is \u+0024. a string with \u+042F random \u+0024. unicodes
This is &#x0024; a string with &#x042F; random &#x0024; unicodes
This is $ a string with Я random $ unicodes
```

Please note that I'm a regex beginner myself so I believe that the must exist more efficient regex-based solution, without any doubt…

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by myself, for anybody who's intrested in this.
It differs a bit from what i've asked, the output does not show unicodes to html entities, but converts them to the corresponding char, because in my case this is better.

So the final portion of code looks like this:

```
# e.g. of an input string containing some sort of unicodes.
# This is how they are formatted in my input file.
my_string =  "This is \u+0024. a string with \u+0024. random \u+0024. unicodes" 

if "\\u+" in my_string :
  unicode_code = (my_string .split("\\u+"))[1].split('.')[0]
  unicode_to_replace = f"\\u+{unicode_code}."
  unicode = f"\\u{unicode_code}"
  # Where the actual unicode is converted to html entity
  html_entity = unicode.encode('utf-8').decode('raw-unicode-escape')
  my_string = my_string .replace(unicode_to_replace, html_entity)


print(my_string)
my_string >> "This is $ a string with $ random $
```